# How do I stop my BMI calculator from adding an unwanted "None" when giving the BMI value?

Tags: python

I created a BMI calculator as a simple beginner project. It all works correctly except that the code outputs an extra piece of unwanted text on an extra line which says "None".

Here's the code:

```
def bmi_calculator(height, weight):
    bmi = weight / (height ** 2)
    print("Your bmi is:")
    print(bmi)
    if bmi > 25:
        print("You are overweight")
    else:
        print("You are healthy")

a = input("What is you're height in metres?")
height = int(a)
b = input("What is you're weight in kilograms?")
weight = int(b)

print(bmi_calculator(height, weight))
```

I expect the output to be (for example):

```
Your bmi is:
60.0
You are overweight
```

However the actual output is:

```
Your bmi is:
60.0
You are overweight
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print()` in your main program should be a simple function call.  The `None` is that `print` displaying the return value of your function -- but your function doesn't *have* a return value; `None` is the default.  The function does all the printing that you want.

```
a = input("What is you're height in metres?")
height = int(a)
b = input("What is you're weight in kilograms?")
weight = int(b)

bmi_calculator(height, weight)
```

Comment: To follow up https://stackoverflow.com/users/11413138/chris, a better design would be to have `bmi_calculator` return the actual BMI and do all of your input & output _outside_ of this function.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved. As for the better design, I thought that my input and output were already outside of the function `bmi_calculator`?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are printing what is returned by the function `bmi_calculator()`. In python all functions return a None if no explicit return is present, which is the case.